# Jenkins slave failing to start

Tags: jenkins

I'm attempting to set up a new Jenkins slave. The slave is a linux machine and has OpenJDK. `java -version` returns

```
java version "1.6.0_39"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.11) (rhel-1.13.11.0.el6_7-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

When I run `java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://server:81/computer/buildmachine/slave-agent.jnlp` the slave seems to initially connect and then immediately hits an exception.

```
Sep 12, 2016 10:57:11 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up slave: buildmachine
Sep 12, 2016 10:57:11 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Sep 12, 2016 10:57:11 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://server:81/]
Sep 12, 2016 10:57:11 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Sep 12, 2016 10:57:11 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to server:8080
Sep 12, 2016 10:57:11 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP3-connect
Sep 12, 2016 10:57:11 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Server didn't accept the handshake: Unknown protocol:Protocol:JNLP3-connect
Sep 12, 2016 10:57:11 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to server:8080
Sep 12, 2016 10:57:11 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP2-connect
Sep 12, 2016 10:57:11 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
Sep 12, 2016 10:57:11 AM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread run
SEVERE: I/O error in channel channel
java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:73)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2349)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:2818)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:803)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:301)
        at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
        at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)
Sep 12, 2016 10:57:11 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
```

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://jenkins.io/blog/2015/04/06/good-bye-java6 :

> Your Jenkins master and all the build slaves need to be running on
>   Java7+

Answer (score 2):

The JRE version was not recent enough. Upgraded to a later version of OpenJDK for Java 1.7 and now slave connects correctly.